# View code generated by IBM's Enterprise COBOL compiler

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos

I have recently started doing some work with COBOL, where I have only ever done work in z/OS Assembler on a Mainframe before.

I know that COBOL will be translated into Mainframe machine-code, but I am wondering if it is possible to see the generated code?

I want to use this to better understand the under workings of COBOL.

For example, if I was to compile a COBOL program, I would like to see the assembly that results from the compile. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Use LIST,NOOFFSET as options to your compile. If you can't change options directly, add `CBL LIST,NOOFFSET` at the beginning of your program (before `ID DIVISION` or `IDENTIFICATION DIVISION` starting after column seven.

Comment: @BillWoodger will LIST really print the assembler listing (or only a COBOL source listing)? If yes this one should really be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @SimonSobisch no, it shouldn't be an answer. It takes two seconds to ask a colleague and five seconds to consult the Enterprise COBOL Pogramming Guide. `Use the LIST compiler option to produce a listing of the assembler-language expansion of your source code.` If you want the listing of the source you specify... `SOURCE`. This takes longer then five seconds to make into an answer, so benefits no-one.

Comment: @SimonSobisch I spent longer than five seconds in the end...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Relenting, only because of this: "I want to use this to better understand the under workings of Cobol".

The simple answer is that there is, for Enterprise COBOL on z/OS, a compiler option, LIST. LIST will provide what is known as the "pseudo assembler" output in your compile listing (and some other useful stuff for understanding the executable program). Another compiler option, OFFSET, shows the displacement from the start of the program of the code generated for each COBOL verb. LIST (which inherently has the offset already) and OFFSET are mutually exclusive. So you need to specify LIST and NOOFFSET.

Compiler options can be specified on the PARM of the EXEC PGM= for the compiler. Since the PARM is limited to 100 characters, compiler options can also be specified in a data set, with a DDName of SYSOPTF (which, in turn, you use a compiler option to specify its use).

A third way to specify compiler options is to include them in the program source, using the PROCESS or (more common, since it is shorter) CBL statement.

It is likely that you have a "panel" to compile your programs. This may have a field allowing options to be specified.

However, be aware of a couple of things: it is possible, when installing the compiler, to "nail in" compiler options (which means they can't be changed by the application programmer); it is possible, when installing the compiler, to prevent the use of PROCESS/CBL statements.

The reason for the above is standardisation. There are compiler options which affect code generation, and using different code generation options within the same system can cause unwanted affects. Even across systems, different code generation options may not be desirable if programmers are prone to expect the "normal" options.

It is unlikely that listing-only options will be "nailed", but if you are prevented from specifying options, then you may need to make a special request. This is not common, but you may be unlucky. Not my fault if it doesn't work for you.

This compiler options, and how you can specify them, are documented in the Enterprise COBOL Programming Guide for your specific release. There you will also find the documentation of the pseudo-assembler (be aware that it appears in the document as "pseudo-assembler", "pseudoassembler" and "pseudo assembler", for no good reason).

When you see the pseudo-assembler, you will see that it is not in the same format as an Assembler statement (I've never discovered why, but as far as I know it has been that way for more than 40 years). The line with the pseudo-assembler will also contain the machine-code in the format you are already familiar with from the output of the Assembler.

Don't expect to see a compiled COBOL program looking like an Assembler program that you would write. Enterprise COBOL adheres to a language Standard (1985) with IBM Extensions. The answer to "why does it do it likely that" will be "because", except for optimisations (see later).

What you see will depend heavily on the version of your compiler, because in the summer of 2013, IBM introduced V5, with entirely new code-generation and optimisation. Up to V4.2, the code generator dated back to "ESA", which meant that over 600 machine instructions introduced since ESA were not available to Enterprise COBOL programs, and extended registers. The same COBOL program compiled with V4.2 and with V6.1 (latest version at time of writing) will be markedly different, and not only because of the different instructions, but also because the structure of an executable COBOL program was also redesigned.

Then there's opimisation. With V4.2, there was one level of possible optimisation, and the optimised code was generally "recognisable". With V5+, there are three levels of optimisation (you get level zero without asking for it) and the optimisations are much more extreme, including, well, extreme stuff. If you have V5+, and want to know a bit more about what is going on, use OPT(0) to get a grip on what is happening, and then note the effects of OPT(1) and OPT(2) (and realise, with the increased compile times, how much work is put into the optimisation).

There's not really a substantial amount of official documentation of the internals. Search-engineing will reveal some stuff. [IBM's Compiler Cafe:COBOL Cafe Forum - IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000002281&p) is a good place if you want more knowledge of V5+ internals, as a couple of the developers attend there. For up to V4.2, here may be as good a place as any to ask further specific questions.

Comment: Back in my college days, this is how I learned how the System/370 (then) worked best, especially when I compared optimized versus un-optimized code. (This was OS Full ANS COBOL V4, that dates me.) It wasn't just the assembler, it was COBOL as well, because you can learn a lot about a compiler from the generated code. I was already heading towards a sysprog career with assembler emphasis, and LIST helped me become a better assembler programmer, as well as COBOL, and PL/I, then C. If you have access to the C compiler, it can provide even more insight, especially with tuning and for architecture.

Comment: @GrapeSoda3 I'm interested in the fact that this sort of thing interests you. Send me an email at my Stack Exchange user name at gmail. Your interest in this is very rare these days, and there are folks who would love to nurture this.